# update cellContent in HTML via vb.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, checkbox

can you please help me to update cellContent in HTML via vb.net. It is Datagrid view in website. Below is inspect HTML:

```html
<div class="grid-controls">
    <form method="post" class="vss-app-form grid-control-popover none" id="gridMorePopover_1346" name="gridMorePopover_1346" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
        <input type="hidden" id="sessionId-gridMorePopover_1346" search-phrase"
```

I want to update here `<div class="cellContent">B0025KV07A</div>` this is inspect element.

Comment: Think you'll do better if you tag this with `vb.net` rather than `vba`

Answer (score 0):

Assign an ID to your div so that you can refer to it by ID.

E.g. if the div ID is `myid`, in VB:

```
WebBrowser1.document. GetElementById("myid").innertext= "new text"
```